# Finding and deleting repeated data entries with two identical features identified by a third unique feature

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm using this code to print the start and stop positions of a subsequence, denoted as SOURCE, within a master sequence. The master sequence is identified by GENE. Some sequences in GENE have two components of DIRECTION, + and -, and these are treated as unique sequences. However, what I did not realize is that in generating the dataset in the first place (by aligning a file of many SOURCE sequences against the GENE sequences), I have more than a few instances where there are multiple "valid" alignments of SOURCE sequences against GENE sequences. I need a way to delete the entries from the SOURCE sequence with the fewest occurrences within a GENE sequence or the smallest range of POS1 to final POS2 in the case of an equal number of SOURCE sequences. I have a sample output below with a clarifying example.

Here is my Python code:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv

##sys.stdout = open("Sampletest2d.txt", "w")
##data = pd.read_csv('Sampletest2.txt', sep='\t')
sys.stdout = open("ExonFileTry1Part3.txt", "w")
data = pd.read_csv('ExonFileTry1.txt', sep='\t')
groups = data.groupby(['GENE', 'DIRECTION'])

fixedgroups = []

for (gene_id, strand), group in groups:
    #print gene_id, strand
    if strand == '+':
        group['POS-1'] = group.POS1
        group['POS-2'] = group.POS2
    else:
        group['POS-1'] = group.POS2
        group['POS-2'] = group.POS1
    #print group
    fixedgroups.append(group)
print fixedgroups
```

Dataset (tab delimited)

```
GENE    DIRECTION   POS1    POS2    SOURCE
TT-1    +   1   16  A1
TT-1    +   130 289 A1
TT-1    +   353 438 A1
TT-1    +   519 580 A1
TT-1    +   665 742 A1
TT-1    +   813 864 A1
TT-1    +   931 975 A1
TT-1    +   1053    1166    A1
TT-1    +   1   16  B2
TT-1    +   130 289 B2
TT-1    +   353 438 B2
TT-1    +   519 580 B2
TT-1    +   665 742 B2
TT-1    +   813 864 B2
TT-1    +   931 975 B2
TT-1    +   1053    1161    B2
BB-2    +   3   659 C3
BB-2    +   3   640 D4
BB-2    -   1093    426 E5
BB-2    -   1093    508 F6
EE-3    +   1   95  G7
EE-3    +   155 377 G7
EE-3    +   439 513 G7
EE-3    +   577 840 G7
EE-3    +   1   95  H8
EE-3    +   155 377 H8
EE-3    +   439 513 H8
EE-3    -   840 577 I9
EE-3    -   513 439 I9
EE-3    -   377 155 I9
EE-3    -   840 577 J10
EE-3    -   513 458 J10
```

Sometimes a GENE has multiple SOURCE sequences and there are more sequences from one SOURCE than another. However, sometimes there are an equal number of sequences from two different SOURCEs, in which case I need to keep the SOURCE with the largest value range between the first POS1 and the last POS2 for that SOURCE.

For example, in GENE TT-1 in the + DIRECTION, there are two SOURCE sets A1 and B2, which both have 8 entries. However, SOURCE A1 has a final POS2 of 1166 while the final POS2 of B2 is 1161, and so B2 has a smaller range and should be deleted.

It took an unbelievable amount of time for me just to understand how to do what I've done already, and that was starting based on a similar code. I feel like I know what I want to do here, but I just don't know the syntax, as I have extremely limited computer science knowledge. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a variation on @D.A.'s answer:

First, some boiler-plate setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''\
GENE    DIRECTION   POS1    POS2    SOURCE
TT-1    +   1   16  A1
TT-1    +   130 289 A1
TT-1    +   353 438 A1
TT-1    +   519 580 A1
TT-1    +   665 742 A1
TT-1    +   813 864 A1
TT-1    +   931 975 A1
TT-1    +   1053    1166    A1
TT-1    +   1   16  B2
TT-1    +   130 289 B2
TT-1    +   353 438 B2
TT-1    +   519 580 B2
TT-1    +   665 742 B2
TT-1    +   813 864 B2
TT-1    +   931 975 B2
TT-1    +   1053    1161    B2
BB-2    +   3   659 C3
BB-2    +   3   640 D4
BB-2    -   1093    426 E5
BB-2    -   1093    508 F6
EE-3    +   1   95  G7
EE-3    +   155 377 G7
EE-3    +   439 513 G7
EE-3    +   577 840 G7
EE-3    +   1   95  H8
EE-3    +   155 377 H8
EE-3    +   439 513 H8
EE-3    -   840 577 I9
EE-3    -   513 439 I9
EE-3    -   377 155 I9
EE-3    -   840 577 J10
EE-3    -   513 458 J10'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(data), sep='\t')
```

Now we add `RANGE` and `SUMRANGE` columns, just as @D.A. did:

```
df['RANGE'] = abs(df['POS2']-df['POS1'])
df['SUMRANGE'] = df.groupby(["GENE", "DIRECTION", "SOURCE"])['RANGE'].cumsum()
print(df)
#     GENE DIRECTION  POS1  POS2 SOURCE  RANGE  SUMRANGE
# 0   TT-1         +     1    16     A1     15        15
# 1   TT-1         +   130   289     A1    159       174
# 2   TT-1         +   353   438     A1     85       259
# 3   TT-1         +   519   580     A1     61       320
# 4   TT-1         +   665   742     A1     77       397
# 5   TT-1         +   813   864     A1     51       448
# 6   TT-1         +   931   975     A1     44       492
# 7   TT-1         +  1053  1166     A1    113       605
# 8   TT-1         +     1    16     B2     15        15
# 9   TT-1         +   130   289     B2    159       174
# 10  TT-1         +   353   438     B2     85       259
# 11  TT-1         +   519   580     B2     61       320
# 12  TT-1         +   665   742     B2     77       397
# 13  TT-1         +   813   864     B2     51       448
# 14  TT-1         +   931   975     B2     44       492
# 15  TT-1         +  1053  1161     B2    108       600
# 16  BB-2         +     3   659     C3    656       656
# 17  BB-2         +     3   640     D4    637       637
# 18  BB-2         -  1093   426     E5    667       667
# 19  BB-2         -  1093   508     F6    585       585
# 20  EE-3         +     1    95     G7     94        94
# 21  EE-3         +   155   377     G7    222       316
# 22  EE-3         +   439   513     G7     74       390
# 23  EE-3         +   577   840     G7    263       653
# 24  EE-3         +     1    95     H8     94        94
# 25  EE-3         +   155   377     H8    222       316
# 26  EE-3         +   439   513     H8     74       390
# 27  EE-3         -   840   577     I9    263       263
# 28  EE-3         -   513   439     I9     74       337
# 29  EE-3         -   377   155     I9    222       559
# 30  EE-3         -   840   577    J10    263       263
# 31  EE-3         -   513   458    J10     55       318
```

For each group with common GENE and DIRECTION, record the index of the row with the biggest SUMRANGE:

```
idx = df.groupby(["GENE", "DIRECTION"])['SUMRANGE'].agg(lambda col: col.idxmax())
print(idx)
# GENE  DIRECTION
# BB-2  +            16
#       -            18
# EE-3  +            23
#       -            29
# TT-1  +             7
# Name: SUMRANGE
```

Select the sub-DataFrame of `df` with columns GENE, DIRECTION, and SOURCE and rows given by `idx`:

```
dfm = df.ix[idx, ['GENE','DIRECTION','SOURCE']]
print(dfm)
#     GENE DIRECTION SOURCE
# 16  BB-2         +     C3
# 18  BB-2         -     E5
# 23  EE-3         +     G7
# 29  EE-3         -     I9
# 7   TT-1         +     A1
```

Do an inner merge on `df` and `dfm`. The keys are the intersection of the common columns of `df` and `dfm` -- namely, GENE, DIRECTION and SOURCE. An "inner" merge keeps only those rows where both `df` and `dfm` share the same keys. So in the resultant merged DataFrame, `df`'s GENE, DIRECTION and SOURCE must match `dfm`'s GENE, DIRECTION and SOURCE. Thus, all rows with the wrong SOURCE are dropped:

```
result = pd.merge(df, dfm, how = 'inner')
print(result)
#     GENE DIRECTION  POS1  POS2 SOURCE  RANGE  SUMRANGE
# 0   TT-1         +     1    16     A1     15        15
# 1   TT-1         +   130   289     A1    159       174
# 2   TT-1         +   353   438     A1     85       259
# 3   TT-1         +   519   580     A1     61       320
# 4   TT-1         +   665   742     A1     77       397
# 5   TT-1         +   813   864     A1     51       448
# 6   TT-1         +   931   975     A1     44       492
# 7   TT-1         +  1053  1166     A1    113       605
# 8   BB-2         +     3   659     C3    656       656
# 9   BB-2         -  1093   426     E5    667       667
# 10  EE-3         +     1    95     G7     94        94
# 11  EE-3         +   155   377     G7    222       316
# 12  EE-3         +   439   513     G7     74       390
# 13  EE-3         +   577   840     G7    263       653
# 14  EE-3         -   840   577     I9    263       263
# 15  EE-3         -   513   439     I9     74       337
# 16  EE-3         -   377   155     I9    222       559
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the great response. Reading through it, it looks like you did exactly what I was looking for. I am getting an error at the end though `line 60, in <module>
    result = pd.merge(data, dfm, how = 'inner')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge'` was I supposed to import something else for pandas to work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry; I can't think of a plausible reason why `pd.merge` should raise an AttributeError. [The merge function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) has been a part of pandas at least since version 0.6. If you are working from an interactive prompt or IDE, you may want to try saving the code to a file (e.g. `script.py`) and running `python script.py` from the command-line. That may eliminate some possible sources of errer.

Comment: I was running it from IDLE, but I tried the command line option and got the same error. Could it have anything to do with the way I loaded my data? I read through the documentation you linked and it seems like I should probably be the weak link here, as pd.merge is definitely a thing...

Comment: Let's do a sanity check: Open up a python interactive interpreter. Type `import pandas as pd`, then `pd.merge`. Do you get an error? Hopefully you get `<function pandas.tools.merge.merge>`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Documents/I.S/Part-2/Sanitycheck.py", line 2, in <module>
    pd.merge
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge'` So should I try reinstalling my pandas and python programs?

Comment: At the interactive prompt, type `pd`. You will see something like `<module 'pandas' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/pandas/__init__.pyc'>`. The directory containing this `__init__.pyc` file is the top level of the pandas package. Go to that directory, and look for the `tools` subdirectory. See if there is a file called `merge.py` inside. That's the file that defines the `pd.merge` function.

Comment: If you don't have the `pandas/tool/merge.py` file, then it is time to reinstall.

Comment: Didn't have it, had to reinstall pandas. It appears to be working, however there is a TypeError now `result = data.merge(data, dfm, how='inner')
TypeError: merge() got multiple values for keyword argument 'how'`. So merge definitely works, but it does not seem to recognize that the value of 'inner' has been supplied? Which is odd because it should default to `inner` unless I'm mistaken. Sorry this is causing so many problems, and thanks for your help so far

Comment: Hold on -- it should be `pd.merge(...)` not `data.merge(...)`.

Comment: Don't know how that happened. Fixed. Thanks so much for your help. I even figured out how to get it to print :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand everything you wrote, but I'm jumping off your data and the 'For example' paragraph, which says "SOURCE A1 has a final POS2 of 1166 while the final POS2 of B2 is 1161, and so B2 has a smaller range and should be deleted".  I'm treading "TT-1 +" and "TT-1 -" as different entities, and I'm summing the ranges for each row.  I think that's what you want.

Add a RANGE column to the DataFrame

```
df['RANGE'] = abs(df['POS2']-df['POS1'])
```

Now accumulate that per source for each sequence, source combination.

```
df['SUMRANGE'] = df.groupby(["GENE", "DIRECTION", "SOURCE"])['RANGE'].cumsum()
```

Extract out the indices of the rows that have maximum 'SUMRANGE' for each sequence.

```
dfm = pandas.DataFrame(df.ix[df.groupby(["GENE", "DIRECTION"]).agg(lambda df: df.idxmax())['SUMRANGE']])
```

Set the index for use in the `join` function that is coming next.

```
dfm.index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dfm['GENE'], dfm['DIRECTION']])
```

Join df and dfm.

```
dfj = df.join(other=dfm['SOURCE'], on=['GENE', 'DIRECTION'], rsuffix='.r')
```

Now filtering dfj down based on whether 'SOURCE' is the same as 'SOURCE.r'.

```
dfj[dfj.apply(lambda x: x['SOURCE'] == x['SOURCE.r'], axis=1)]

    GENE DIRECTION  POS1  POS2 SOURCE  RANGE  SUMRANGE SOURCE.r
0   TT-1         +     1    16     A1     15        15       A1
1   TT-1         +   130   289     A1    159       174       A1
2   TT-1         +   353   438     A1     85       259       A1
3   TT-1         +   519   580     A1     61       320       A1
4   TT-1         +   665   742     A1     77       397       A1
5   TT-1         +   813   864     A1     51       448       A1
6   TT-1         +   931   975     A1     44       492       A1
7   TT-1         +  1053  1166     A1    113       605       A1
16  BB-2         +     3   659     C3    656       656       C3
18  BB-2         -  1093   426     E5    667       667       E5
20  EE-3         +     1    95     G7     94        94       G7
21  EE-3         +   155   377     G7    222       316       G7
22  EE-3         +   439   513     G7     74       390       G7
23  EE-3         +   577   840     G7    263       653       G7
27  EE-3         -   840   577     I9    263       263       I9
28  EE-3         -   513   439     I9     74       337       I9
29  EE-3         -   377   155     I9    222       559       I9
```

Of course, you can delete the unwanted columns from `dfj` if you want.  For reference, here is the DataFrame I started with.

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
    GENE DIRECTION  POS1  POS2 SOURCE
0   TT-1         +     1    16     A1
1   TT-1         +   130   289     A1
2   TT-1         +   353   438     A1
3   TT-1         +   519   580     A1
4   TT-1         +   665   742     A1
5   TT-1         +   813   864     A1
6   TT-1         +   931   975     A1
7   TT-1         +  1053  1166     A1
8   TT-1         +     1    16     B2
9   TT-1         +   130   289     B2
10  TT-1         +   353   438     B2
11  TT-1         +   519   580     B2
12  TT-1         +   665   742     B2
13  TT-1         +   813   864     B2
14  TT-1         +   931   975     B2
15  TT-1         +  1053  1161     B2
16  BB-2         +     3   659     C3
17  BB-2         +     3   640     D4
18  BB-2         -  1093   426     E5
19  BB-2         -  1093   508     F6
20  EE-3         +     1    95     G7
21  EE-3         +   155   377     G7
22  EE-3         +   439   513     G7
23  EE-3         +   577   840     G7
24  EE-3         +     1    95     H8
25  EE-3         +   155   377     H8
26  EE-3         +   439   513     H8
27  EE-3         -   840   577     I9
28  EE-3         -   513   439     I9
29  EE-3         -   377   155     I9
30  EE-3         -   840   577    J10
31  EE-3         -   513   458    J10
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post. Haha sorry about it being kind of vague, I think it's because I've spent so much time with it, I forget it might be unclear. I tried Unutbu's solution first, just because I understood his explanation better. However I'm getting kind of a similar error with both of them with the joining the data frame and the dfm with `.join`. I get `KeyError: "no item named <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>\nIndex: 700 entries, 330.0 to 1226.0\nData columns:\nGENE 700  non-null values\nDIRECTION 700  non-null  values\nSOURCE 700  non-null values\ndtypes: object(3)"`